# Custom Taxonomy List, Selection floats to top

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called Slide set up:

```
register_post_type('slide', [
    'labels' => [
        'name' => __('Slide'),
        'singular_name' => __('Slide'),
    ],
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'capabilities' => array(
        'create_posts' => false,
    ),
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-universal-access',
]);
```

I then have a custom taxonomy for it, called Group:

```
$groupLabels = [ ... ];
register_taxonomy('Groups', 'slide', ['hierarchical' => true, 'labels' => $groupLabels]);
```

This works fine - I can create Groups, nest them, and [tag a Slide with them](http://grab.by/zbqk). The problem is when I go into the edit page for a Slide ( /wp-admin/post.php?post=202&action=edit ) and select some Groups then save it, the Groups I selected [float to the top of the list, out of hierarchy order](http://grab.by/zbpC). The weird thing is if I go to the Quick Edit (while still on the list page) it [displays correctly](http://grab.by/zbqu).

Does anyone have ANY idea what's going on? I don't even know where to start looking, and Googling for anything like this just brings back completely unrelated results because it's too specific.

Answer (score 0):

After way too much Googling, here's a fix :)

```
add_filter('wp_terms_checklist_args', function ($args) {
    $args['checked_ontop'] = false;
    return $args;
});
```